# Is there a way to determine what javascript makes a very specific change to DOM element

Tags: javascript

I am working in a Magento site that has numerous javascript files attached to it, and I am trying to determine which line in which file is changing an input. I have tried adding an attribute breakpoint to the script, but the problem is I have to basically hold down F9 for a couple minutes before the actual change occurs, and by the time it does, I have zoomed right past it. Clicking through one at a time takes about half hour to find the actual script, but I don't want to do this every time, especially when I know what change I am looking for.

So, is there something potentially in Chrome Dev Console that can break only on a script that is making a particular change to a particular element? In my case, there was a JS line that removed whitespace from an input that I didn't want it to remove whitespace from. So something that says something like, "If this JS snippet removes whitespace from this element, stop the code execution and display the code snippet and it's location"

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015197/can-i-break-with-debugger-on-all-changes-to-a-dom-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I break with debugger on all changes to a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015197/can-i-break-with-debugger-on-all-changes-to-a-dom-element)